# Prevent Up-Down control for Tab Control?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

As documented:

> "If not all tabs can be shown at once, the tab control displays an up-down control so that the user can scroll additional tabs into view."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760550%28VS.85%29.aspx

I don't want this. I don't want an up down control to show if I have too many and I don't want multiline tabs. I want a single strip. I will handle the case of too many tabs with a control I create myself, but I don't want the up-down control. Thanks

Comment: @User: Can you add a reference, where is this documented?

Comment: See edit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760550%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no style for that, so i believe the only way is a bit of hacking. From what i can see with my Spy++, the updown control is a true child control of the tab control with id = 1. So, you can actually hide it with ShowWindow().